# error on installing openshift origin using oo-installer

Tags: openshift-origin

I'm trying to install and configure openshift origin using oo-installer based on [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-openshift-origin-on-centos-6-5) tutorial.

But i face some issues on applying puppet.

```
Warning: Config file /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml not found, using Hiera defaults
Warning: Variable access via 'fqdn' is deprecated. Use '@fqdn' instead. template[inline]:1
(at /usr/lib/ruby/siteruby/1.8/puppet/parser/templatewrapper.rb:76:in `methodmissing')
Warning: Scope(Class[Openshiftorigin::Plugins::Dns::Nsupdate]): Generate the Key file with '/usr/sbin/dnssec-keygen -a HMAC-MD5 -b 512 -n USER -r /dev/urandom -K /var/named apps.example.com'
Warning: Scope(Class[Openshiftorigin::Plugins::Dns::Nsupdate]): Use the last field in the generated key file /var/named/Kapps.example.com*.key
Error: bindkey is required. at /etc/puppet/modules/openshiftorigin/manifests/plugins/dns/nsupdate.pp:30 on node master.openshift.example.com
Error: bindkey is required. at /etc/puppet/modules/openshift_origin/manifests/plugins/dns/nsupdate.pp:30 on node master.openshift.example.com
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm trying to install it and I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to Generate the Key File as stated by executing the 'dnssec-keygen' command - '/usr/sbin/dnssec-keygen -a HMAC-MD5 -b 512 -n USER -r /dev/urandom -K /var/named apps.example.com'

The dnssec-keygen utility will generate a SecureDNS key file located in the '/var/named' directory that was specified.

Get the contents of the key file that was generated by executing - 'cat /var/named/Kapps.example.com.*.key | awk '{print $8}''

The format for the key returned by the last command should resemble 'CNk+wjszKi9da9nL/1gkMY7H+GuUng=='. This key is set in the bind_key puppet parameter.

For example, in my generated puppet origin configuration file add the following key to it - 
bind_key => 'CNk+wjszKi9da9nL/1gkMY7H+GuUng==',